# AngularJS controller is not reaching webapi

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In the interest of crawling before walking with angularjs, I have created a simple application to display results from a sql server table using webapi. unfortunately the webapi is never called, because the routing is wrong, but I am not sure how to resolve. fiddler shows a 404 error.

the cshtml  is as follows, defining the app and controller.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var app = angular.module('streamApp', []);

app.controller('streamController', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.addMode = false;

    //Used to display the data   
    $http.get('/api/Stream/').success(function (data) {
        $scope.streams = data;
        $scope.loading = false;
    })
    .error(function () {
        $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading streams!";
        $scope.loading = false;
    });

});

</script>
```

the rendering section in the cshtml file is

```
<div data-ng-app="streamApp" data-ng-controller="streamController" class="container">
....
</div>
```

The webapi class is in a folder named WebApi in the MVC project, but since it is never reached, there is no point in displaying its code. it is non-descript anyway.

The route config is as follows:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

I am not sure if I need to specify route instructions in angularjs code or in mvc route config, and exactly what functions or configuration to supply. I have tried moving the webapi class to the Controllers folder with the same results - http 404. Any advice on how to make this example get to the webapi code would be appreciated.

---

well hot-diggity....I solved the immediate problem by adding the annotation to my webapi class method

```
    [Route("api/stream")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Models.StreamViewModel> Get()
    {
       .....
    }
```

so now the question is should something be done with RouteConfig as a better practice? Or is the Route() annotation the preferred way to go? or is it 6 of one half a dozen of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to your updated question , Best Practice of routing**:

Route() annotation is the preferred way of doing this.

> MVC 5 supports a new type of routing, called attribute routing. As the
>   name implies, attribute routing uses attributes to define routes.
>   Attribute routing gives you more control over the URIs in your web
>   application.
>
> The earlier style of routing, called convention-based routing, is
>   still fully supported. In fact, you can combine both techniques in the
>   same project.

There are other advantages of attribute routing like

> 1. It puts the route information adjacent to the controller action that
>      implements that route. This helps in debugging and troubleshooting,
>      as well as providing an ability to quickly search for route
>      information in your solution.
> 2. It reduces risk in the process of making changes to routes. In RouteConfig.cs or WebApiConfig.cs (in the case of Web API solutions),
>      the possibility exists to inadvertently change the wrong route or
>      otherwise adversely affect other parts of your application.
> 3. You may also want to include acceptable HTTP methods, permitted user types and registration priorities, which if included with the
>      attribute-based routes, put all of that information together in one
>      place.

This post provided inspiration and reinforcement for me on the above, and goes into more detail: 
http://kevinmontrose.com/2011/07/25/why-i-love-attribute-based-routing/

Answer (score 0):

You can use either, but without the annotation your endpoint would have been `api/get` not `api/stream` (assuming you didn't rename your method).

Answer (score 0):

First , you should use ApiController rather then Controller, as it take a role of an api action.

Second, If we take a look, it looks like you created a controller named ApiController, and a function called Stream. Otherwise, its a misunderstanding of the designing your web integration using MVC.

App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs:

```
using System.Web.Http;

class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
using System.Web.Http;

...

protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

and ApiControllerNameController: //The Controller word closes the file name, and will be reached without writing it:

```
using System;
..
..
..

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values/MethodName
        public IEnumerable<int> MethodName()
        {
            return new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        }
    }
}
```